# Suggested practice to communicate error messages to UI

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, error-handling

What method can you suggest to handle error messages from API to UI?

In other projects I have worked on, we sent error codes to the UI, then the UI reads the corresponding message from a file, which could be just another class or resx. They say is useful for localization.

I have read somewhere that it's a good practice to throw exceptions. I am just worried that the program would crash if the error was not caught at the UI side.

I'm using WPF for the UI, and will be using WCF later on for the services. It's a windows application.

Comment: WinForms? ASP.NET? WCF?

Comment: If you have an error that is not handled then your program has a bug or is encountering adverse conditions it cannot handle (e.g. no more memory) and the best thing is probably that it crashes.

Comment: @volpav, I'm using WPF for the UI, and will be using WCF later on for the services. It's a windows application.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, does it mean that I can just throw everything from my API's? I don't have to return an error code? I'm working on the back end of the application, so I need to remind the front-end guys they shouldn't forget to catch errors when they use my libraries.

Comment: @Gemini: In my opinion returning error codes is almost always a bad practice. At every layer in your code you have to check for these codes and if you forget your code may get into an inconsistent state. Cleanup can be a nightmare etc. Throw exceptions when abnormal conditions happen. Catch and rethrow exceptions (without losing the stack trace) if you need to clean up or augment the error description. Handle exceptions at the top level of your application and fail fast if you get into a state you cannot handle.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinLiversage. I think throwing and catching exceptions would encourage us to be more careful in supplying function parameters for the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest throwing normal .NET exceptions in case there's an error on the API side. The big disadvantage of using error codes is that depending on how the layers of your application are organized (DAL -> Business Logic -> API -> UI), it might be very problematic to propagate and handle them.

With exceptions, you can handle them easily at any level (by using `try-catch` construct) and either re-throw (e.g. when you only need to log an exception and there's a code further down the stack that is supposed to handle it on its own) or "swallow" them (not generally recommended, though).

As for how to handle errors on the UI level, I'd let them "flow" all the way up and then "decorate" them (e.g. by showing a modal dialog with some details and troubleshooting tips). For example, if you're working with Web APIs, you can just return appropriate HTTP statuses (401, 403, 500) from your API and handle them on the client by having an error hook, like `$.ajaxError` which will show some sort of modal dialog. Here you're not inventing your own way of reporting errors but rather leveraging what's already defined by HTTP specs (and therefore, it's very easy to understand the behavior as well as to respond to it).

I'm not that familiar with WPF, but I think there should be something similar to `Application_Error` in WinForms - an event handler where you can examine the error and "decorate" it by showing some nice modal dialog to the user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will redesign my codes to do exception handling.